# Are these two cost functions equivalent in octave?

Tags: machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent, non-linear-regression

```
one = sum((X*theta) - y) .^2)/(2*m);
two = ((X'*theta - y)*(X*theta - y) ) / 2*m;

% where X' == X transpose, so I can do matrix multiplication.
```

"One" is used(successfully) for a uni-variate cost function for linear regression.
"One" seems to also work for calculating the cost for a multivariate linear regression problem.

"Two" is the formula suggested for multi-variate approach in a very popular machine learning course :)

Are they the same methods, or did "One" just work per chance on a multi-variate tranning set maybe.

Comment: Depends on the dimensions of `X`, `theta` and `y`.

Comment: Yes good point, the idea is that any sort of matrix multiplication would be possible and in this case all values in all matrices are real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second formula doesn't look correct to me.

Demo:

```
>> theta = [2;3];
>> X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8];
>> y = [7;8;9;10];
>> m = length(y);
>> ((X'*theta - y)*(X*theta - y) ) / 2*m
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x4, op2 is 2x1)
```

first formula seems to be correct if we fix a problem with the missing parentheses:

```
>> sum(((X*theta) - y) .^2)/(2*m)
ans =  155.75
```

alternative vectorized formula:

```
>> (X * theta - y)' * (X * theta - y) / (2*m)
ans =  155.75
```

Comment: Yeh, nice - thanks. It turns out, that expanding an equation like this just makes things clearly when building this in something like Octave.